# Emgu CV for Android throwing Exception Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: opencv, xamarin.android, emgucv

I am using Mono for Android and followed the instructions mentioned on this page: http://file.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Emgu_CV_for_Android but when I run the application on the emulator, it throws the following exception:

> Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError has been thrown Cannot load library:
>   find_library[1199]:    37 'libopencv_highgui.so' failed to load
>   previously
>
> Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library:
>   find_library[1199]:    37 'libopencv_highgui.so' failed to load
>   previously   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticVoidMethod (IntPtr
>   jclass, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00023] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.4-branch/9f7cbd60/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:973
>
> at Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary (System.String libName)
>   [0x00034] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mac-monodroid-4.2.4-branch/9f7cbd60/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-15/src/generated/Java.Lang.JavaSystem.cs:253
>
> at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor () [0x00000] in :0
>
> --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library:
>   find_library[1199]:    37 'libopencv_highgui.so' failed to load
>   previously
>
> ```
>   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
>
>   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
>
>   at
> ```
>
> mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.n_onClick(Native
>   Method)
>
> ```
>   at
> ```
>
> mono.android.view.View_OnClickListenerImplementor.onClick(View_OnClickListenerImplementor.java:29)
>
> ```
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
>
>   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
>
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
>   at
> ```
>
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>
> ```
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

Here is a screenshot of OpenCV-2.4.2 reference
[image: Reference Screenshot]

Comment: Does your APK contain these libs?

Comment: Yes, lib folder has these files in the apk

Comment: Does folder `/data/data/yourapp/lib/` contains these libs?

Comment: yes it contains all the files of lib folder.